# Change Toolbar Background

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Hi i have an activity with relative layout in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
the result is 
[image]

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

    tools:context="spydroid.ir.dorobar.Activities.SearchActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:src="@drawable/profile_blure"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
                    android:paddingRight="7dp">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ac_back_btn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_back_arrow" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ac_more"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_more_vert" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/user_all_info_margin_right"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_all_info_margin_right"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textDirection="rtl">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:hint="@string/name_hint" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_primary_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:textDirection="rtl">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="@string/confrimed"
                        android:textColor="@color/confrimed" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_mobile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:hint="@string/mobile_hint" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="58dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_phone"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_primary_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textDirection="rtl">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
                        android:text="@string/confrimed"
                        android:textColor="@color/confrimed" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/user_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:hint="@string/email_hint" />


                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="58dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
                    android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_primary_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_all_info_margin_right">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/user_sex"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/user_old"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:prompt="@string/old_hint" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_all_info_margin_right">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/user_province"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:prompt="@string/province_hint" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_all_info_margin_right">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/user_city"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:prompt="@string/city_hint" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_my_rits"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="رویدادهای شرکت کرده"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subheading" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_fav_rits"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="رویداد های مورد علاقه "
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subheading" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_folow_artists"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="هنرمندانی که آن هارا دنبال میکنم"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/subheading" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_delete_all_location"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_delete_margin_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="حذف کلیه اطلاعات مکانی من"
                android:textColor="@color/md_red_500"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption" />

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/tv_delete_account"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/user_info_padding_top"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="حذف حساب کاربری"
                android:textColor="@color/md_red_500"
                android:textSize="@dimen/caption" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

what i have to do for this ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx).

Comment: hi @SurenderKumar .. its change my Toolbar's background to transparent but i don't want  this .....

Comment: What you actually want? You want status bas color orange?

Comment: i fix color of toolbar back color... i want to this image is be under status bar when i that  instruction my status bar change to transparent but still be below of status bar ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `AppBarLayout`, as seen in the [cheesesquare example app's layout](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_detail.xml)

Comment: that's true just when i  use   
 <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

anyway thanks @ianhanniballake